# Scenario outline title displays parameter name instead of its value in allure report

Tags: python-2.7, allure, python-behave

I have a next scenario outline:

```
Scenario Outline: Create a user with <user_role> role.
   Given select "<user_role>" role

   Examples: roles
      | user_role  |
      | admin      |
```

When I execute this scenario in IDE (PyCharm) I see parameter value in scenario outline title. But when I execute via command line and generate a report (json, xml, html) only parameter name displayed in report.

How it can be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you were getting this [issue](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/issues/212), upgrade allure-python to 2.5.0.